# Surprising declining response to my flag for deletion

Tags: support, status-completed, declined-flags, vote-to-delete

I wrote a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084145) which I was able to solve myself later, however, the solution was not useful for anyone else (*very* localized issue). I tried to delete the question, but since it had been answered already, this was impossible:

> Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead

I was notified to flag it for mod attention, which I did:

> Question solved, answer is not useful for others, please delete the question.

This lead to an interesting surprise when I later found this:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

So... what am I to do?

Comment: Delete the answer, then delete the question?

Comment: None of the answers have upvotes. You should be able to delete it.

Comment: I cannot delete the question itself (said message popped up). Are you saying I should delete the answers? I'm afraid that would be quite rude to the people who were unfortunate enough to put them up.

Comment: @Mysticial "Users can delete their own questions if the question: ..only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes" It has two, so the OP wouldn't be able to delete.

Comment: @Kendra Ah. I didn't know about the "multiple answers" part.

Comment: @mafu It may be a case of you didn't explain well enough that _you_ couldn't delete the question yourself, because of the two answers on the question. You probably should've added that you had tried to delete yourself and received an error that you could not. Mods have a lot of flags to handle, so sometimes if it's not obvious that they should double check the question, they won't. The text you provided sounds more like a "I'm lazy, delete this for me." type of message, or could be construed as such.

Comment: @Kendra That sounds very reasonable. I will flag it again with this information included.

Comment: Yeah... If there's one thing I've noticed reading through some of these flagging questions, it's you need to provide as much information as possible in your "Other" flag if you want a good chance of getting it acted on properly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert Harvey took care of it. Accepted self answer because no close reason for Q is fitting.